# Python BeautifulSoup Mix Matching items in Table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Im attempting to select data from a table  using Bs4 and storing to a csv file but the columns are mixmatched. I feel like my HTML statements in in my if condition is wrong.

```
def grab_daily_data(self): 
    url_template='http://boxofficemojo.com/movies/?page=daily&view=chart&id=%s.htm'
    #url=http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?page=daily&view=chart&id=hungergames3.htm #Testing
    for val in self.mov_id:
        print 'parsing through: %s'%val
        url=url_template%val
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

        alltables=soup.findAll("table", {"border":"0", "width":"95%"})
        in_mainbody=False
        i=0;counter=0;test_arr=[]; change=[]
        for table in alltables:
            rows=table.findAll('tr')
            for tr in rows:
                cols=tr.findAll('td')
                for td in cols:
                    test=td.text

                    if i>=17:
                        if counter%10==0:
                            print test
                            self.day_num.append(test)
                        counter+=1


                    i+=1
```

My problem is that the column shifts over to left by 1 and every 7 rows it shifts over again.

Sample output:
instead of printing out:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6
7
8
9
10...
```

It prints out:

```
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu

8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not getting to the appropriate `table`.

Rely on the chart element, get the [next `table` sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and find all rows inside:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?page=daily&view=chart&id=hungergames3.htm'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

for tr in soup.find('div', id='chart_container').find_next_sibling('table').find_all('tr')[1:]:
    print [td.text for td in tr('td')]
```

Prints:

```
[u'Fri', u'Nov. 21, 2014', u'1', u'$55,139,942', u'-', u'-', u'4,151', u'$13,284', u'$55,139,942', u'1']
[u'Sat', u'Nov. 22, 2014', u'1', u'$40,905,873', u'-25.8%', u'-', u'4,151', u'$9,854', u'$96,045,815', u'2']
[u'Sun', u'Nov. 23, 2014', u'1', u'$25,851,819', u'-36.8%', u'-', u'4,151', u'$6,228', u'$121,897,634', u'3']
[u'Mon', u'Nov. 24, 2014', u'1', u'$8,978,318', u'-65.3%', u'-', u'4,151', u'$2,163', u'$130,875,952', u'4']
[u'Tue', u'Nov. 25, 2014', u'1', u'$12,131,853', u'+35.1%', u'-', u'4,151', u'$2,923', u'$143,007,805', u'5']
[u'Wed', u'Nov. 26, 2014', u'1', u'$14,620,517', u'+20.5%', u'-', u'4,151', u'$3,522', u'$157,628,322', u'6']
[u'Thu', u'Nov. 27, 2014', u'1', u'$11,079,983', u'-24.2%', u'-', u'4,151', u'$2,669', u'$168,708,305', u'7']
[u'']
[u'Fri', u'Nov. 28, 2014', u'1', u'$24,199,442', u'+118.4%', u'-56.1%', u'4,151', u'$5,830', u'$192,907,747', u'8']
[u'Sat', u'Nov. 29, 2014', u'1', u'$21,992,225', u'-9.1%', u'-46.2%', u'4,151', u'$5,298', u'$214,899,972', u'9']
[u'Sun', u'Nov. 30, 2014', u'1', u'$10,780,932', u'-51.0%', u'-58.3%', u'4,151', u'$2,597', u'$225,680,904', u'10']
[u'Mon', u'Dec. 1, 2014', u'1', u'$2,635,435', u'-75.6%', u'-70.6%', u'4,151', u'$635', u'$228,316,339', u'11']
[u'Tue', u'Dec. 2, 2014', u'1', u'$3,160,145', u'+19.9%', u'-74.0%', u'4,151', u'$761', u'$231,476,484', u'12']
[u'Wed', u'Dec. 3, 2014', u'1', u'$2,332,453', u'-26.2%', u'-84.0%', u'4,151', u'$562', u'$233,808,937', u'13']
[u'Thu', u'Dec. 4, 2014', u'1', u'$2,317,894', u'-0.6%', u'-79.1%', u'4,151', u'$558', u'$236,126,831', u'14']
...
```

Comment: Thanks again @alecxe. Can you recommend any website or books where I can learn more about HTML and bs4?

Comment: @user3667623 You are welcome. Well, official docs is a very good place to start. Then, sort the questions in [beautifulsoup] tag by vote and look through the most popular threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup?sort=votes&pageSize=50.